# R in QGIS not working after change of computers

Tags: qgis, r

I have installed, uninstalled a couple of times, but still get the same issue.  Windows 7 and QGIS 3.6.1 and latest versions if R and R Studio.  It used to work perfect until I changed computers.

```
R execution console output
Warning in install.packages("sf", dependencies = TRUE) :
'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("sf", dependencies = TRUE) :
unable to install packages
Calls: tryCatch ... tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous> -> install.packages
Execution halted
```

Comment: Could you post your R provider settings? If you are using R Studio, user library folder (default) would be `C:/Users/your_username/R/win-library/4.0`. I suggest to use it in the provider setting, too. (Then the libraries downloaded in R Studio becomes automatically accessible from QGIS).

Comment: R Folder = C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3, User Library Folder = C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library, R scripts folder = C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\rscripts

Comment: Its working. Many Thanks.  Will test some further R scripts.